# Error “An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll”

Tags: c#

I get error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file >'c:\Tvarkarastis\Tvarkarastis.txt' because it is being used by another process.

when I try to use

```
private void sukurtiFailąToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\", "Tvarkarastis");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        string fileName = "Tvarkarastis.txt";
        pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Create(pathString);
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\Tvarkarastis", "Tvarkarastis.txt");
            string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Prašome atsidaryti failą ir jį pakeisti. Failas yra : " + pathString + Environment.NewLine);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(pathString, lines);
        }
```

This function tries to create a file and write to it. Function works if I disable writing and leave just the file creation.
Im new to coding so please excuse me if there is something silly in the code or my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is being locked on creation as using `File.create()` generates a FileStream for the new file, when creating files you should have the creation within a `using` directive and then continue your code from there:

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(pathString)))
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Prašome atsidaryti failą ir jį pakeisti. Failas yra : " + pathString + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {

                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```